# "or" operator in Python query

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I'm a beginner in Python, trying to make a simple program combining everything I've learnt so far. In this question the program itself is not the question, but a specific part of it, which I have worked around, but wanted some insight into why this is happening.

```
def printresults (answer):
    if answer == "y" or "Y":
        print ("Yes")
    else:
        print ("No")
```

In the case above, I have managed to get this function to run with "N" as the 'answer'. The issue I faced was that it would then run the first if-branch, and in this case print "Yes", despite it not being a "y" or a "Y".

I have since worked around this issue by creating a new variable in the function and using the lower() method to make only one possibility, and then simply asking it to determine if it is "y" or not.

```
def printresults (answer):
    lwranswer = answer.lower()
    if lwranswer == "y":
        print ("Yes")
    else:
        print ("No")
```

I therefore suspect the fault lies with me somehow misusing the "or" operator - I just don't know how or why. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks

*Note, the program won't simply return a Yes or No, but I made it print these to troubleshoot and see which branch it was taking.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here, unsing `or` but this requires the full clause:

```py
if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
```

or using `in` and a collection (sets work best, but tuples and lists are also valid alternatives in this case):

```py
if answer in {"y", "Y"}:
```

Comment: Better yet use a `set`, e.g. `answer in {'y', 'Y'}`

Comment: sets are not sequences, though. They are just collections. See also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

Answer (score 0):

When using the `or` or `and` operator. You need to specify the other clause as well.

```
if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us quickly analyze why:

```
answer == 'y' or 'Y'
```

does not work the way you intended.

The expression is evaluated as following:

```
(answer == 'y') or 'Y'
```

because `==` has higher precedence than `or`.

The `answer == 'y'` part behaves as intended, i.e. evaluates to `True` if `answer` is `'y'` and `False` otherwise.

Now, `x or y` [operates](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in such a way that *"if x is false, then y, else x"*.
For non-boolean arguments, such as strings, the concept of `True`/`False` is extended to [*Truthy*/*Falsy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false).

Therefore, when `answer` is `'y'`, it returns `True` as expected, and when `answer` is **not** `'y'`, it returns `'Y'`, which is *Truthy*, no matter if the value of `answer` is actually `'Y'` or not.

Similarly, if you were to evaluate `'y' or 'Y'`, you would get
`'y'` again because `'y'` is *Truthy*.

This means that you cannot simply use parenthesis to let the above expression behave the way you expected.

The recommended way to achieve the intended behavior is:

```
answer in {'y', 'Y'}
```

For a comprehensive discussion of *"how to test a variable against multiple values"* please refer to [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) , which, aside from swapping the role of variable and value, is precisely what you would need.